# Votes Cast information not displayed correctly!

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

The new look "Votes Cast" in user profile is very informative and a good idea from Stack Exchange team. But it seems to have a flaw of not displaying the vote downs correctly.

I have down voted ONLY twice and I am sure of that. I did run a query and found the following data: [image]

Where as, my profile shows 0 down votes:
[image]

Now, to be sure, I checked the data of other users and found both vote down and vote ups messed up. One of my sample was [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov). It seems both his values are not correct.

Comment: I'm seeing it fine, did you try a hard refresh? There were issues with this earlier but they should be resolved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget the data explorer data is approximately a month old.

If the posts you down-voted have been deleted since the last data dump then they won't appear on your profile, but will still be in the data dump.

If you notice your up-votes are now 244 but are reported as 221 in the data dump.

*P.S. circles should be freehand.*